# PictureBox moving left to right to left repeatedly

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2015

Trying to use this code so that the picturebox will move from left to right by itself automatically. The code doesn't give any errors but when I run the app, the picturebox1 just stays still and does nothing.

I'm thinking: Timer1 properties maybe, didn't mess with anything in the timer1 properties, not sure if I'm supposed to, or maybe I have to add more code or fix it; not sure.

(If you are curious what I'm doing in case that helps, I'm having an 'enemy' move back and forth from left to right to left to right and so on, and the 'player' has to get past it without hitting it.)

```
Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
    Do
        PictureBox1.Left = PictureBox1.Left - 5
        If PictureBox1.Left <= 5 Then
            Do
                PictureBox1.Left = PictureBox1.Right + 5
            Loop Until PictureBox1.Left >= 1000
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: that procedure is not hooked up to a timer

Comment: im new to this, can you (not asking for code or anything) just tell me how to do that possibly?

Comment: use a timer component from the toolbox.  that looks like code you made up and called it `Timer`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @user3697824 mentioned, the Sub you posted is not connected to the Timer on your form. Generally when using timers, you put the code you want to run in the Timer's `Tick` method.

```
Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    'Your code goes here.
End Sub
```

You could potentially fix your code above by adding a `Handles Timer1.Tick` statement to the end of the Sub's signature like this:

```
Private Sub Timer1_Timer() Handles Timer1.Tick
    Do
        PictureBox1.Left = PictureBox1.Left - 5
        If PictureBox1.Left <= 5 Then
            Do
                PictureBox1.Left = PictureBox1.Right + 5
            Loop Until PictureBox1.Left >= 1000
        End If
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: So I got it working (I think) but the split second the picturebox moves (I can see it move like just a tiny bit to the left) the app freezes and I have to force close.

Comment: I found the problem. Change the line in the nested do loop from `PictureBox1.Left = PictureBox1.Right + 5` to `PictureBox1.Left = PictureBox1.Left + 5`. To slow the movement down a bit you can adjust Timer1's interval property. 

This may not be the technique you want to use though as it causes the image to flicker. You should instead look into some graphics libraries like DirectX or OpenGL, or a game engine such as Unity or Unreal as they will handle all the graphics code for you!

Comment: Also, if my response answered your question, please mark it as the answer. :)